# Same query - different execution plans

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

SQL 2008.
I have a test table:

```
create table Sale
(
    SaleId int identity(1, 1)
        constraint PK_Sale primary key,
    Test1 varchar(10) null,
    RowVersion rowversion not null
        constraint UQ_Sale_RowVersion unique
)
```

I populate it with 10k test rows.

```
declare @RowCount int = 10000
while(@RowCount > 0)
begin
    insert Sale default values
    set @RowCount -= 1
end
```

I run these two queries:

```
-- Query #1

select *
from Sale
where RowVersion > 0x000000000001C310

-- Query #2

declare @LastVersion rowversion = 0x000000000001C310

select *
from Sale
where RowVersion > @LastVersion
```

I can't figure out why these two queries have different execution plan.
Query #1 does index seek against UQ_Sale_RowVersion index.
Query #2 does index scan against PK_Sale.

I want query #2 to do index seek.
I would appreciate some help.
Thank you.

**[Edit]**

Tried using datetime2 instead of rowversion. The same issue.

I tried to force using index too (query #3)

```
select *
from Sale with (index = IX_Sale_RowVersion)
where RowVersion > @LastVersion
```

This seemed to show the same query execution plan as the query #1, but execution plan showed this query #3 as the most expensive among all those 3 queries.

**[Edit]** Execution plan:

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan"
              Version="1.1"
              Build="10.50.1600.1">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementText="-- Query #1&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;select *&#xd;&#xa;from Sale&#xd;&#xa;where RowVersion &gt; 0x000000000001C310&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;-- Query #2&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;"
                    StatementId="1"
                    StatementCompId="1"
                    StatementType="SELECT"
                    StatementSubTreeCost="0.00657038"
                    StatementEstRows="1"
                    StatementOptmLevel="FULL"
                    QueryHash="0xE442FF9A4A2A630A"
                    QueryPlanHash="0x347569CFDEF2A13F"
                    StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound"
                    ParameterizedText="(@1 varbinary(8000))SELECT * FROM [Sale] WHERE [RowVersion]&gt;@1">
          <StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true"
                                ARITHABORT="true"
                                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true"
                                ANSI_NULLS="true"
                                ANSI_PADDING="true"
                                ANSI_WARNINGS="true"
                                NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/>
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="24"
                      CompileTime="1"
                      CompileCPU="1"
                      CompileMemory="136">
            <RelOp NodeId="0"
                    PhysicalOp="Nested Loops"
                    LogicalOp="Inner Join"
                    EstimateRows="1"
                    EstimateIO="0"
                    EstimateCPU="4.18e-006"
                    AvgRowSize="28"
                    EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00657038"
                    Parallel="0"
                    EstimateRebinds="0"
                    EstimateRewinds="0">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="SaleId"/>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="Test1"/>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="RowVersion"/>
              </OutputList>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="0">
                <OuterReferences>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                    Schema="[dbo]"
                                    Table="[Sale]"
                                    Column="SaleId"/>
                </OuterReferences>
                <RelOp NodeId="1"
                        PhysicalOp="Index Seek"
                        LogicalOp="Index Seek"
                        EstimateRows="1"
                        EstimateIO="0.003125"
                        EstimateCPU="0.0001581"
                        AvgRowSize="19"
                        EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831"
                        TableCardinality="10000"
                        Parallel="0"
                        EstimateRebinds="0"
                        EstimateRewinds="0">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="SaleId"/>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="RowVersion"/>
                  </OutputList>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="1"
                              ScanDirection="FORWARD"
                              ForcedIndex="0"
                              ForceSeek="0"
                              NoExpandHint="0">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                          Schema="[dbo]"
                                          Table="[Sale]"
                                          Column="SaleId"/>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                          Schema="[dbo]"
                                          Table="[Sale]"
                                          Column="RowVersion"/>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                            Schema="[dbo]"
                            Table="[Sale]"
                            Index="[UQ_Sale_RowVersion]"
                            IndexKind="NonClustered"/>
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <StartRange ScanType="GT">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                                Schema="[dbo]"
                                                Table="[Sale]"
                                                Column="RowVersion"/>
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="0x000000000001C310">
                                <Const ConstValue="0x000000000001C310"/>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </StartRange>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp NodeId="3"
                        PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek"
                        LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek"
                        EstimateRows="1"
                        EstimateIO="0.003125"
                        EstimateCPU="0.0001581"
                        AvgRowSize="16"
                        EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831"
                        TableCardinality="10000"
                        Parallel="0"
                        EstimateRebinds="0"
                        EstimateRewinds="0">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="Test1"/>
                  </OutputList>
                  <IndexScan Lookup="1"
                              Ordered="1"
                              ScanDirection="FORWARD"
                              ForcedIndex="0"
                              ForceSeek="0"
                              NoExpandHint="0">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                          Schema="[dbo]"
                                          Table="[Sale]"
                                          Column="Test1"/>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                            Schema="[dbo]"
                            Table="[Sale]"
                            Index="[PK_Sale]"
                            TableReferenceId="-1"
                            IndexKind="Clustered"/>
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                                Schema="[dbo]"
                                                Table="[Sale]"
                                                Column="SaleId"/>
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Sale].[SaleId]">
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                                    Schema="[dbo]"
                                                    Table="[Sale]"
                                                    Column="SaleId"/>
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </Prefix>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@1"
                                ParameterCompiledValue="0x000000000001C310"/>
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
              <StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;declare @LastVersion rowversion = 0x000000000001C310&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;"
                  StatementId="2"
                  StatementCompId="2"
                  StatementType="ASSIGN"/>
        <StmtSimple StatementText="&#xa;select *&#xd;&#xa;from Sale&#xd;&#xa;where RowVersion &gt; @LastVersion"
                    StatementId="3"
                    StatementCompId="3"
                    StatementType="SELECT"
                    StatementSubTreeCost="0.0328005"
                    StatementEstRows="3000"
                    StatementOptmLevel="FULL"
                    QueryHash="0xE442FF9A4A2A630A"
                    QueryPlanHash="0x0C6238F821406F2B"
                    StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound">
          <StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true"
                                ARITHABORT="true"
                                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true"
                                ANSI_NULLS="true"
                                ANSI_PADDING="true"
                                ANSI_WARNINGS="true"
                                NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false"/>
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="16"
                      CompileTime="1"
                      CompileCPU="1"
                      CompileMemory="144">
            <RelOp NodeId="0"
                    PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan"
                    LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan"
                    EstimateRows="3000"
                    EstimateIO="0.0216435"
                    EstimateCPU="0.011157"
                    AvgRowSize="28"
                    EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0328005"
                    TableCardinality="10000"
                    Parallel="0"
                    EstimateRebinds="0"
                    EstimateRewinds="0">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="SaleId"/>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="Test1"/>
                <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                  Schema="[dbo]"
                                  Table="[Sale]"
                                  Column="RowVersion"/>
              </OutputList>
              <IndexScan Ordered="0"
                          ForcedIndex="0"
                          NoExpandHint="0">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="SaleId"/>
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="Test1"/>
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                      Schema="[dbo]"
                                      Table="[Sale]"
                                      Column="RowVersion"/>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                        Schema="[dbo]"
                        Table="[Sale]"
                        Index="[PK_Sale]"
                        IndexKind="Clustered"/>
                <Predicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Sale].[RowVersion]&gt;[@LastVersion]">
                    <Compare CompareOp="GT">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[AdventureWorks]"
                                            Schema="[dbo]"
                                            Table="[Sale]"
                                            Column="RowVersion"/>
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="@LastVersion"/>
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Are your Statistics up to date?

Comment: I ran statics update - didn't help. Also, I am not sure if statistics can be out of date in this case, as the table is created and populated from scratch, it didn't have a chance to get statistics distorted. Anyway, even if statistics was screwed up, why the first query works as should, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: I'm thinking its a parameter sniffing issue - just to humor me, could possibly try declaring @LastVersion first (with no default) and then set it your desired variable on the next line...

Comment: I tried this too. Didn't work either. I would be surprised if it did :).

Comment: can you re-run both with "set showplan_xml on" turned on

Comment: Added execution plan to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Query 2 uses a variable.

At the time the batch is compiled SQL Server does not know the value of the variable so just falls back to heuristics very similar to `OPTIMIZE FOR (UNKNOWN)`

For `>` it will assume that 30% of the rows will end up matching (or 3000 rows in your example data). This can be seen in the execution plan image as below. This is significantly over and above the 12 rows (0.12%) which is [the tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx) for this query in whether it uses a clustered index scan or a non clustered index seek and key lookups.

You would need to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get it to take account of the actual variable value as shown in the third plan below.

[image: Execution Plans Image]

### Script

```
CREATE TABLE #Sale
(
    SaleId INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Sale PRIMARY KEY,
    Test1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    RowVersion rowversion NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT UQ_Sale_RowVersion UNIQUE
)

/*A better way of populating the table!*/
INSERT INTO #Sale (Test1)
SELECT TOP 10000 NULL 
FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2

GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sale
WHERE RowVersion > 0x000000000001C310-- Query #1


DECLARE @LastVersion rowversion = 0x000000000001C310

SELECT *
FROM #Sale
WHERE RowVersion > @LastVersion-- Query #2


SELECT *
FROM #Sale
WHERE RowVersion > @LastVersion
OPTION (RECOMPILE)-- Query #3

DROP TABLE #Sale
```

Comment: So, was it tipping or not, sorry can't tell?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a covering index for the actual data that you need to retrieve and avoid `select *`, depending on the data in your table that's the only sure thing that will force SQL Server to not *tip* and fallback to a scan.

> A covering index is an index in which the search filter is in the same order and each output column is included in the index.

Also, since we're dealing with parameterization, it's worth trying to see if `optimize for unknown` has any impact on the execution plan here.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - Changed it, thanks for pointing it out. I'm a neat freak myself.

Comment: @Goran - No it shouldn't. It is actually the fact that it is doing something very similar to `OPTIMIZE FOR (UNKNOWN)` that is causing the OP's problem.

Comment: I'm with @Matrin on this as well, hence, I'm a bit vauge, there are several things when dealing with parameters that cause the execution plan to behave differently and once it's cached, you'll have to recompile it to see the effect of any changes you make (invalidate the cache).

Comment: Yes, covering index would help, but it would not explain why execution plans a different for two similar queries. Also,covering index is not a good option in my case, as my real table has about 20 columns and I need all of them in my query. So covering index would need even more space to store than the table itself, and the table is huge. Also, query always suppose to retrieve very small subset of rows (close to zero).